# Datatables: all columns maximum size

Tags: html, css, datatables

I'm using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) with ajax data request (json format) and dynamic columns load. This is my actual code:

```
var tableData;
var tableName='#iuprTable';

$(document).ready(function (){

    jQuery.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "table/"+document.getElementById("hiddenIdCar").value,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},  
        beforeSend: function() {
            waitingModal.showPleaseWait();
        },
        success: function(data,status,xhr){
            //No exception occurred
            if(data.success){
                tableData = data.result;
                $.each(tableData.columns, function (k, colObj) {
                    var str = '<th data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<b>NAME</b>:'+ colObj.parName + '<br><b>DESCRIPTION</b>:' + colObj.description + '<br><b>NOTE</b>: ' + colObj.note + '"></i>' + colObj.parName + '</th>';
                    $(str).appendTo(tableName+'>thead>tr');
                });
            } else {
                waitingModal.hidePleaseWait();
                notifyMessage(data.result, 'error');
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr,status,e){
            window.location.href = "/500";
        }
    }).complete(function() {
        //initialize datatable
        if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( tableName ) ) {
            var iuprTable = $(tableName).DataTable({
                scrollCollapse: true,
                scrollX:        true,
                scrollY:        '60vh',
                paging:         false,
                "data": tableData.data,
                "columns": tableData.columns,
                fixedColumns:   {
                    leftColumns: 4
                },
                "initComplete": function(settings){
                    //TOOLTIP cell
                    $(tableName+ ' tbody td').each( function (k, cellObj){
                        this.setAttribute( 'title', cellObj.innerText );
                        this.setAttribute( 'data-toggle', "tooltip" );
                    });
                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
                        container: 'body'
                    }); 
                    //add timeout because otherwise user could see a too fast waiting modal
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        waitingModal.hidePleaseWait();
                    }, 1000);       
                } 
            });
        }
        else {
            iuprTable.ajax.url("table/"+document.getElementById("hiddenIdCar").value).load();
        }
    }); 
});

function notifyMessage(textMessage, typeMessage){
    $.bootstrapGrowl(textMessage, {
        type: typeMessage, // (null, 'info', 'error', 'success')
    });
}
```

To cut cell text and to apply tooltip I have used this css:

```
<style>
#rdiTable td {
   white-space: nowrap; 
   text-overflow:ellipsis; 
   overflow: hidden; 
   max-width:1px;
}
/*Change the size here*/
.tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 550px;
}
.tooltip
{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>
```

I don't know why but some columns cut the text and other are over 1000px like below image:
[image]
I have tried whit max-width, with "columnDefs", with HTML and CSS but I have always this problem.
Do you know what might be the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try a [fixed table layout](https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/).

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: No changed, I think it is something about cells or columns, but it's odd that only some columns give me this problem.